# Redirect from wp-includes to 404 Error page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My goal is to redirect the user when visit anything in the wp-includes directory to a custom 404 page. I am trying to hide any evidence that I am running WordPress and block out any hackers.

I don't want the default Forbidden message that Apache has setup by default so instead use one of WordPress 404.php templates instead.

I have tried the HTACCESS file method but it affects any css, jpg, and js files. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the wordpress docs a read. They have an entire page on **Hardening Wordpress**. See the section on **Securing wp-includes:**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-includes

```
# Block the include-only files.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  AudicerStudio wants a 404 response, not a 403 Forbidden response.  The code you provided will respond with a 403, not a 404.